# PAGE LIMIT IN ITEXTPDF-5.5.8 in JAVA

Tags: itext

Is there a limit in pages using itextpdf-5.5.8 (open source) in java? I set the page below

```
Document document = new Document();
Rectangle xpagesize = new Rectangle(850,1100);
document.setPageSize(xpagesize);
```

I have a large amount of data to display in PDF. But it shows that the pages are limited in 35 pages only. If I exceeded to 35 above, the pages crashed and no data displayed.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please share enough code to reproduce the issue. Furthermore you say *the pages crashed and no data displayed* - no data displayed in a specific PDF viewer? It could also be an issue of that viewer. Please also share the PDF in question, e.g. via a public share on dropbox or google drive you post the URL of here.

Comment: There is no "35 page" limit in iText. I can make documents with hundred thousands of pages.

Comment: There is... I tested it and I've noticed that it is limited to 35 pages only. Maybe it is an open source. Is there any licence to make it unlimited? Below are some part of a sample code.                                                           for(int x=0; x <= 100; x++) { document.newPage(); PdfContentByte cb = writer.getDirectContent();
        cb.saveState();
        cb.beginText();
        cb.setFontAndSize(bf, 14);
        cb.moveText(xpos, ypos); cb.showText("Hello World"); cb.endText();
        cb.restoreState(); }

Comment: Hi @Bruno Lowagie. I used Phrase and ColumnText instead of cb.savetext()... etc. Now it's already working. It can print more than 35 pages up to thousands. Thank you to ITEXT